# Consistent appearance for Windows Forms applications

Tags: user-interface, styles, winforms, appearance

Is there a way to apply consistent visual appearance for multiple Windows Forms applications? So that the same color scheme is used, etc? Or you have to do it manually?

(I apologize for this question, but I have googled it without any real answer - a couple of pointers in the right direction or a few links would be enough. I have also searched here, so if it is a repost please close it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used components from Developer Express to do this. Take a look at: [DevExpress .NET Windows Forms Skinning Library](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/)

There are probably other resources out there for this, depending upon your needs...

Comment: Thank you both for your answers - I suspected this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a consistent appearance that is *different* from the standard Windows appearance, then you have to do it by hand - possibly with the assistence of some sort of 3rd party skinning library.